# Help with a really strange COM+ callstack

Tags: c++, com, visual-foxpro

We have a legacy COM+ dll that is called by an old ASP application.  It is periodically crashing, and the call stack is very strange looking

It appears that a call to DllUnregisterServer and to CoInstall appear within the call stack (we don't dynamically install/uninstall anything within the code -- it's just querying a database).

I am wondering if it is possible that MSI "file protection" is kicking in and causing the crash.  Do you think that's possible?  any way I can dig up more information? (it's an old VFP applicaiton, so I don't think I can get proper debug symbols)

Here's the call stack:

```
Call Stack: 
vfp9t! + 0x2272f
vfp9t!VFPDllGetClassObject + 0xb6
ctcvccomasyncproxy!DllGetClassObject + 0x3e
ole32!CoInitializeSecurity + 0x5ff5
ole32!CoInitializeSecurity + 0x5bdc
ole32!CoGetTreatAsClass + 0x2a2
ole32!CoInitializeSecurity + 0x3a2b
COMSVCS!DispManGetContext + 0xbc07
ole32!CoInitializeSecurity + 0x3a2b
ole32!CoInstall + 0x6ed
ole32!CoQueryAuthenticationServices + 0x21aa
ole32!CoQueryAuthenticationServices + 0x2c56
ole32!CoGetContextToken + 0xd48d
ole32!CreateStreamOnHGlobal + 0x1b7c
ole32!CoCreateObjectInContext + 0xd9f
ole32!CoInstall + 0x903
ole32!CoGetContextToken + 0x12f5b
RPCRT4!NdrServerInitialize + 0x1fc
RPCRT4!NdrStubCall2 + 0x217
RPCRT4!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke + 0x82
ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile + 0x13b27
ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile + 0x13ad4
ole32!DcomChannelSetHResult + 0xaab
ole32!DcomChannelSetHResult + 0x495
ole32!CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx + 0xb06
ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile + 0x139e1
ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile + 0x13872
ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile + 0x12d59
ole32!CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx + 0x9f5
ole32!CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx + 0x9c0
USER32!LoadCursorW + 0x4cf5
USER32!LoadCursorW + 0x4e86
USER32!TranslateMessageEx + 0x10d
USER32!DispatchMessageW + 0xf
COMSVCS!DllUnregisterServer + 0x270
COMSVCS!DllUnregisterServer + 0x180
COMSVCS!DllUnregisterServer + 0xc6c
COMSVCS!DllUnregisterServer + 0xf4d
msvcrt!_endthreadex + 0xa3
kernel32!GetModuleHandleA + 0xdf
```

Comment: `GetModuleHandle` must be used with caution in a multi-threaded application. Perhaps you'd be better off with `GetModuleHandleEx` but there isn't much to go on here.

Comment: One of the problems that we have is that this is not a C++ object -- it's Visual Fox Pro, so the Call to GetModuleHandle isn't under our control -- the code we have access to just calls CreateObject(), the call stack is just showing code that was called on our behalf.

Comment: So this is incompatible buggy code that you can't change but need to use? The final release of FoxPro was 7 years ago ... good luck!

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to use debug symbols to obtain *real* call stack. The one you posted above is misleading and is only using exported entry points to approximately locate function names. See [How to use a symbol server with the Visual Studio .NET debugger](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319037) for details.

Comment: @AJG85 stuck with it for now - c# replacement is on the way, but won't come nearly soon enough.  Thanks for wishing me luck -- we're gonna need it!

Comment: @RomanR Problem is the code isn't .NET code, and we don't have a crash dump, just a logged call stack.

Comment: @JMarsch, BTW one of the possible causes can be that an old component is not DEP friendly, and is kicked by DEP. Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066577/com-interop-fails-when-moving-to-new-server) out, who knows if disabling DEP could be a solution here.

Comment: @Roman R.  Thank you -- We have run into problems with DEP before, and it could be the cause of this one.  We will end up excluding this process or disabling DEP to see what happens.  One of the things that makes this crash tough to figure out is that we have not been able to repro in a test environment.  Just happens in production sometimes.  We've been using every bit of telemetry that we can get our hands on to try to figure  it out -- Windows logs, logging that comes with the app, etc.  So, we are trying without DEP, but only time will tell if it's a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ole32!CoInstall + 0x6ed

The +0x6ed offset is an important 'quality' indicator.  What it tells you is that the return address is 1773 bytes from the *known* address of CoInstall.  That's rather a lot.  The stack trace builder just didn't have any other known address that was closer so it could only offer CoInstall as a guess.  Once the offset goes beyond 0x100, the odds that the code is actually part of the indicated known function start to dwindle rapidly.

There are a lot of entries in the trace that have huge offsets.  Making the entire trace rather low quality.  Editing the stack trace and leaving only good quality lines in place:

```
vfp9t!VFPDllGetClassObject + 0xb6
ctcvccomasyncproxy!DllGetClassObject + 0x3e
...
RPCRT4!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke + 0x82
...
USER32!DispatchMessageW + 0xf
```

Which is a pretty standard stack trace for a cross-apartment request to get a COM object class factory.  Why it failed is not guessable, you don't have debug symbols for foxpro and didn't document the HRESULT.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I knew that without symbols, the dump was a longshot.  To the best of my knowledge, the symbols that I need are not published, so it does not look as though we are going get our answers from the dumps.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. That stack dump does not appear to be plausible.  It is almost certainly not useful.
2. I suggest writing an unhandled exception handler and trying to get it to crash again.  Your handler can try to do a better stack dump or even a proper crash dump.
   See

   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634.aspx
   - http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/Exception/Exception.aspx
   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx

The handler would be in your code that calls the dll code.

Comment: I won't be able to get debug symbols for teh VFP runtime.  Do you think that I will get anything useful without them?  If so, I can try to get a minidump.  I'm afraid that without those symbols, I'm looking at a dead end.  What do you think?

Comment: I won't suggest it will be easy, but sometimes you can get useful information.  If the crash is in Windows code that has been called by VFP, you might get a clue from the params passed to the Windows function.  If it is in the VFP code you can, at least, check the params you pass to the VFP entry point, though the actual fault may be several levels down.  If truly desperate you can try to debug the assembly code.  That's hard, but not impossible.  You should be able to figure out whether it is a bug or if Windows is shutting it down on purpose for security reasons.

Comment: If you can catch the exception you can try to decode it.  There might be an error message or other useful info attached.  Max Pietrik's article (second link above) is a good start on how to do that.